Example 1.2 Nonlinear Control Khalil
$f( x) =\begin{bmatrix}
x_{2}\\
-sat( x_{1} +x_{2})
\end{bmatrix}$
is not continuously differentiable on $R^2$. Using the fact that the saturdation function sat(.) satisfies $|sat(\eta)-sat{\xi}|$, we obtain:
(1)
$ \begin{array}{l}
||f( x) -f( y) ||^{2} \leq \ ( x_{2} -y_{2})^{2} +( x_{1} +x_{2} -y_{1} -y_{2})^{2}\\
\leq ( x_{1} -y_{1})^{2} +2( x_{1} -y_{1})( x_{2} -y_{2}) +2( x_{2} -y_{2})^{2}
\end{array}$
using inequality:
(2)
$
a^{2} +2ab+2b^{2} =\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}^{T}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix} \leq \lambda _{max}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}\right\} \ \cdot \begin{Vmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}
\end{Vmatrix}^{2}$
we conclude that
(3)
$||f( x) -f( y) ||\leq \sqrt{2.618} \ ||x-y||$
Question 1:
How are they getting from the nonlinear system $f(x)$ to the the equation (1). I cannot follow it at all. I see that the end inequality in (1) leads to the analysis in inequality (2)
Question 2:
I see the inequality (2) as a bowl in 3 dimensional space. I calculated the $ \lambda _{max} =\frac{1}{2}\left( 3+\sqrt{5}\right)=\sqrt{2.618}$. Am I correct in thinking they are satisfying the inequality by simply scaling the second bowl up by $\lambda _{max}$?
(this might not be the right way to think about this)
